# How to prevent a specific node from being killed during GKE node pool resize

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

While reducing number of nodes in node pool in GKE, I want a specific node to be not killed by GKE. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in detail [here](http://This%20might%20help:%20https://pminkov.github.io/blog/removing-a-node-from-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-gke-google-container-engine.html) - you can drain and delete the instance from the instance group (Not direct delete instance)

```
kubectl drain gke_instance_name  --force
```

The delete from instance group command followed by wait-until-stable command:

```
$ gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete-instances $GROUP_ID --instances=gke_instance_name

$ gcloud compute instance-groups managed wait-until-stable $GROUP_ID
```

This will not allow you to blacklist some instances from being deleted - but other way around that you can delete specific instances and leave others untouched.

Comment: Thanks ~vishal for detailed comment